# remove a subpart from the middle of a video

Tags: shell, ffmpeg

I am trying to remove a middle part from a video from 2 to 3 seconds using FFMPEG.  So that the video plays with the start, and the end but without the middle part between 2 to 3 seconds.

This page helped a little bit
https://superuser.com/questions/681885/how-can-i-remove-multiple-segments-from-a-video-using-ffmpeg

My code is as follows:-

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]trim=start=2:end=3,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, concat[out1]" - map [out1] output_without_2_to_3_secs.mp4
```

However with this code I get the following error message

Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 1 on filter Parsed_concat_2.  I'm using a Mac.

Any suggestions much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You need to extract start-2 and 3-end and then concat them.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex '
    [0:v] trim=duration=2 [p1];
    [0:v] trim=start=3, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS [p2];
    [p1][p2] concat
' output.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you, this code works.  However, it also leaves 1 second of black at the end of the video.  I guess this has something to do with the 1 second that I trimmed ?
Is there a way to trim the 1 second of blackness at the end aswell ?

Comment: @OneWorld If `input.mp4` has an audio stream you need to trim it as well.